# Can't uncheck newest on SO (but not meta)

Tags: bug, new-nav

I just enabled the new nav, and I like it, but I checked the `newest` box under `All Questions` in the Where are my tabs? box, and now I can't uncheck it.

On FF 51.0.1 x32 Windows

Note that the problem disappears after a simple refresh of the page, which I didn't think to do until Kendra pointed that out below...

Comment: Repro'd on Chrome 56.0.2924.87 on Windows 7. For anyone else trying to repro, you don't even need to refresh the screen. I did close and reopen the "Where are my tabs?" menu, but I'm not sure even that's necessary.

Comment: The funny thing is, that I *want* to uncheck that box now.  Especially since I can't, I presume

Comment: Had a thought and did another test: Have you tried refreshing the page? This _does_ work correctly for me if I refresh the page.

Comment: Ha!  A simple refresh fixes it!  Hooray!